# -> must point to class/struct/union/generic type error

Tags: c++, multithreading

```
typedef struct{
    IMAGE *fuente;
    IMAGE *destino;
    int saltos;
} ARGTHREAD;

ARGTHREAD values;

DWORD WINAPI ProcessThread(LPVOID arg){

    int i,j,imageRows,imageCols,C,R;
    PIXEL *pfte,*pdst;
    PIXEL *v0,*v1,*v2,*v3,*v4,*v5,*v6,*v7;

    //memcpy(arg->destino, arg->fuente,sizeof(IMAGE)-sizeof(PIXEL *));

    imageRows = arg->fuente->infoheader.rows;//error here ->
    imageCols = arg->fuente->infoheader.cols;//error here ->

    //arg->destino->pixel=(PIXEL *)malloc(sizeof(PIXEL)*imageRows*imageCols);

    i=arg->saltos;//error here ->
    R=imageRows-1;
    C=imageCols-1;
    while(i<R){
                j=1;        
            while(j<C){
                pfte=arg->fuente->pixel+imageCols*i+j;//error here ->
                v0=pfte-imageCols-1;
                v1=pfte-imageCols;
                v2=pfte-imageCols+1;
                v3=pfte-1;
                v4=pfte+1;
                v5=pfte+imageCols-1;
                v6=pfte+imageCols;
                v7=pfte+imageCols+1;

                pdst=arg->destino->pixel+imageCols*i+j;//error here ->

            if(abs(blackandwhite(*pfte)-blackandwhite(*v0))>DIF ||
                    abs(blackandwhite(*pfte)-blackandwhite(*v1))>DIF ||
                    abs(blackandwhite(*pfte)-blackandwhite(*v2))>DIF ||
                    abs(blackandwhite(*pfte)-blackandwhite(*v3))>DIF ||
                    abs(blackandwhite(*pfte)-blackandwhite(*v4))>DIF ||
                    abs(blackandwhite(*pfte)-blackandwhite(*v5))>DIF ||
                    abs(blackandwhite(*pfte)-blackandwhite(*v6))>DIF ||
                    abs(blackandwhite(*pfte)-blackandwhite(*v7))>DIF){

                    pdst->red=0;
                    pdst->green=0;
                    pdst->blue=0;
                }

                else{
                    pdst->red=255;
                    pdst->green=255;
                    pdst->blue=255;
                }
                j++;        
            }
        i = i+numProc;
    }
}
```

**This is how i have created my tread:**

> myThread = CreateThread(NULL, 0,
>   (LPTHREAD_START_ROUTINE)ProcessThread, &values, 0, NULL );

**Im getting a lot of these errors and i cant figure it out why?**

Error 8 error C2228: left of '.cols' must have class/struct/union

Comment: `arg` is type `void*` -- how do you expect `arg->fuente` to work?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`arg` is a `void*` pointer, you can't get anything out of it without first casting it back to the appropriate type:

```
ARGTHREAD* arg_values = static_cast<ARGTHREAD*>(arg);
// use arg_values->...
```

Answer (score 0):

Your program requests an element of a `void*`, which is not a type (with members). First cast it to the type you have passed (`ARGTHREAD`), then you can treat the `void*` as `ARGTHREAD*`.